# Show loading image gif while submit the form until page redirects in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to show a loading icon to users until the form submit and another page elements are fully loaded (`send.php`). How can i do that with javascript and I want to do it with JavaScript or jQuery. Here is my code:

**Index.html**

```
<body>
   <form name= "myform" id= "CC" action="send.php" >
       .
       .
       .
   </form>
</body>
```

**send.php**

```
<body>
    <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```

**CSS**

```
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(images/loader-64x/Preloader_2.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: use a display:none for the loader then use fadeout

Comment: here form haveing large number of post elements, so index page showing up when i use the display none, i want to disable the html page after submit form and mean time loader need to show till the end send.php page completes.